# Insert but on duplicate - add existing and new values together (typeORM)

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Using TpeORM in my typescript application.

Trying to do a simple SQL - insert into tablet values BUT on duplicate - update.

I have a table `User` with columns `id points`. If given data does not exist (based on `ID`) it should insert. But if such an ID exists - it should update. But the points HAVE to sum up.

example: If the existing user has 500 points and in data it's 200 - then in on duplicate it should come up with 700 points (sum up the two)

I tried many code variations. Stuck on this one:

```
TEM.createQueryBuilder()
  .insert()
  .into(UserModel)
  .values({ id: mentionedUser.id, points: amount })
  .orUpdate(["points"], ["user"])
  .execute();
```

**Scenario**

Data: `{id: 1, points 200}`

Database: `[{id: 1, points: 500}]`

IF: in table User with prim key `id` 1 does not exist - insert User `{id: 1, points: 200}`

BUT: if exist then UPDATE the user with ID 1 so its data looked like `{id: 1, points: 700}` (200 (new) + 500 (current))

But with this code above what happens is on duplicate just changes the points value to `200` rather then adding those two numbers together.

NOTE: using mysql